# How to fix formatting difference in Wordpad and Notepad for textfiles in Java?

Tags: java, format, string-formatting, notepad, wordpad

I am using Java to generate an file, but I can't get the formatting right when opened in different Viewers. The programs that give the different output are `WordPad` and `NotePad`.

The output of the program in the console is all well formatted. Also when I view the file in `WordPad` it is also well formated. But when I open the file in `NotePad`, it is all jumbled up.

It looks extremely bad in NotePad and I would hate for the end user to open it up in NotePad seeing a jumbled mess.

Is there a way to properly format text in Java so any text reader would render it like I intended it to be?

I am using `String.format()` to format my strings.

Edit: 
Here is some of the core code I am using to write out the information.

```
private void retrieveOrderInfo(ArrayList<String> order) {
    int row = orderTable.getRowCount();
    String descr[] = new String[row];
    double price[] = new double[row];
    String info;
    readOrderTable(descr, price);
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        info = String.format(" %-45s %-20.1f ", descr[i], price[i]);
        order.add(info);
    }
}

private void writeString(String path, String info, boolean line) {
    DataRW write = new DataRW();
    write.writeFileExternal(path, info, line);
}
```

This is in my DataRW class.

```
public void writeFileExternal(String fileName, String info, boolean line) {
    BufferedWriter bwriter = null;
    try {
        FileWriter fwriter = new FileWriter(fileName, true);
        bwriter = new BufferedWriter(fwriter);
        bwriter.write(info);
        if (line) {
            bwriter.newLine();
        }
        bwriter.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //e.printStackTrace();
        //System.out.println("Could note write to " + fileName);
        errorMessageNotify("writeexternalfile", fileName);
    } finally {
        if (bwriter != null) {
            try {
                bwriter.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                //Just ignore if couldnt close
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So I get the information and just write it out with these method calls.

Edit: Links to images
http://i1248.photobucket.com/albums/hh489/EberronBruce/NotepadDemo_zpsangaprji.jpg

http://i1248.photobucket.com/albums/hh489/EberronBruce/wordpad_zpscbu0adkb.jpg

Here are the links to the images to describe what I mean. I do not have enough reputation points to posts the images directly.

I really do appreciate all the help. I been banging my head on this for a long time. I tried using \t and adjusting the formatting to get it to look right, but then it looks off in Wordpad, MS Word, and FireFox once I get it to look right under NotePad.

Comment: Is it completely different? or only the new-line differs?   how exactly do you write to the file?  which encoding are you using? what have you tried so far?

Comment: Could you edit your question and add the format code in it? That way we could help you. Also, If you could give me the image link, I'll paste it in for you.

Comment: you can upload images somewhere (http://imgur.com/) and put link here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing that the generated code uses UNIX newlines. Wordpad breaks at UNIX linebreaks. Notepad does not.

If you want correct breaks for your OS, use `System.getProperty("line.separator")`

Edit:
Now that we have screenshots, I can say that your problem is with notepad. Change font to a fixed-width font such as Courier, and your data will be properly aligned.

Comment: Sounds plausible, but how could he fix that then?

Comment: I had to actually add write lines in my code to get line breaks in the formatting in text file for Notepad. So I was able to get line breaks. However, I am creating a table so it can be viewed quickly. So, lining up columns is the primary issue. Again, if I could post the images, you would see exactly what I am talking about. :(